# Adding $\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{1/2}+\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^{3/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to refresh my algebra skills by reading the book Elements Of Algebra by Leonhard Euler. I came across a problem:

> $$\text{Add}\;\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{1/2}\;\text{to}\;\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^{3/2}. \qquad\qquad \text{Ans.}\;\frac{b^2+c^2}{b\sqrt{bc}}$$

I don't know how he did it. My understanding is that you can't add radicals that are not the same; for example, $\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3}$

Could someone enlighten me? Or did he use a some properties of radicals?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You can't always *simplify* a sum of two radicals, but you can always add them. The number $\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3}$ is a perfectly valid number, which you can approximate using a calculator. Sometimes, you can also simplify too, e.g. $$\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{12} = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{4}\sqrt{3} = \sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{3} = 3 \sqrt{3}.$$

Comment: It's not true for $b=c=-1$: Take care of absolute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)^{1/2} + \left(\frac{c}{b}\right)^{3/2} = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}} + \frac{\sqrt{c^{3}}}{\sqrt{b^{3}}} = \frac{\sqrt{b}\times\sqrt{b^{3}} + \sqrt{c}\times\sqrt{c^{3}}}{\sqrt{cb^{3}}} = \frac{b^{2}+c^{2}}{b\sqrt{bc}}
\end{align*}

Comment: hi user1337, i see so he add it using the normal fraction addition. Does this mean that we can also do it for $\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{8}$  ?